# WordPress Lightbox Gallery: Making a word link open to an image gallery

Tags: wordpress, image, hyperlink, gallery, thumbnails

I'm trying to get a word link to open to a lightbox gallery. What I mean is having a word like 'Random Room Name' open to a lightbox gallery showcasing the images of the room itself. I can get the media files into the page, but I can't figure out how to link the images to a specific word.

Answer (score 0):

Not long ago, I did something like that.
To see if it helps you

```
$keyword = 'lorem ipsum';
$image_url = 'https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg';
$link_lighbox = '<a href="'$image_url'" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="'.$keyword.'">'.$keyword.'</a>';

$content_with_lightbox = str_replace($keyword, $link_lighbox, get_the_content());
```

This code is ugly, sorry ^^

Comment: Will this coding work if there is more than 1 image for the gallery?